# Using Silvlight, custom EF POCO, custom Validation - leveraging Metadata and its not working in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, reflection, metadatatype

I am using metadata validation for both my MVC and SIlverlight together. However, the classes for silverlight arent working, and I think its due to the MetadataTypeAttribute that doesn't exist for silverlight 4. This seems to be the only thing holding by this part of my project... I am trying to avoid doing everthing custom as I dont like to reinvent the wheel, however the validation classes dont seem to render expected results..:

**Here is my solution for CLR:**

```
var metadataAttrib = this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true).OfType<MetadataTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            var buddyClassOrModelClass = metadataAttrib != null ? metadataAttrib.MetadataClassType : this.GetType();
            var buddyClassProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(buddyClassOrModelClass).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
            var modelClassProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType()).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();

        var brokenRules = from buddyProp in buddyClassProperties
                          join modelProp in modelClassProperties on buddyProp.Name equals modelProp.Name
                          from attribute in buddyProp.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
                          where !attribute.IsValid(modelProp.GetValue(this))
                          select new BrokenRule() { FieldName = buddyProp.Name, ErrorMessage = attribute.FormatErrorMessage("") };

        brokenRulesList = brokenRules.ToList();
```

... And here is the code for Silverlight

```
var metadataAttrib = this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true).OfType<MetadataTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            var buddyClassOrModelClass = metadataAttrib != null ? metadataAttrib.MetadataClassType : this.GetType();
            var buddyClassProperties = buddyClassOrModelClass.GetType().GetProperties();
            var modelClassProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);

            var validationResults = from buddyProp in buddyClassProperties
                                join modelProp in modelClassProperties on buddyProp.Name equals modelProp.Name
                                from attribute in buddyProp.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ValidationAttribute>().Cast<ValidationAttribute>()
                                where buddyProp.Name == modelProp.Name
                                select attribute.GetValidationResult(modelProp, validationContext);

            brokenRulesList = new List<BrokenRule>();
            foreach (ValidationResult vr in validationResults)
            {
                foreach (string memberName in vr.MemberNames)
                    brokenRulesList.Add(new BrokenRule() { FieldName = memberName, ErrorMessage = vr.ErrorMessage });

            }
```

... However, the silverlight code is not working.. Here is the test case...

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
    public partial class User
    {
        public partial class UserMetadata
        {

         [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserIDValidationMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AppResources))]
            public System.Guid ID { get; set; }

            public Nullable<int> UID { get; set; }

         [Display(Name="UserUsernameLabel", Description="Username", ResourceType=typeof(AppResources))]
         [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserUsernameValidationMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AppResources))]
         [StringLength(70, ErrorMessageResourceName="UserUsernameValidationMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AppResources))]
            public string Username { get; set; }

         [Display(Name="UserFirstNameLabel", Description="First Name", ResourceType=typeof(AppResources))]
         [StringLength(90, ErrorMessageResourceName="UserFirstNameValidationMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AppResources))]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I made a class for silverlight which lets it compile, but its not working - as expected..

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
{
    public class MetadataTypeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public MetadataTypeAttribute(Type t)
        {
            MetadataClassType = t;
        }

        public Type MetadataClassType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
}
```

**Does anyone know how to simply leverage to metadata classes for silverlight? Why the metadatatypeattribute isn't there I dont know. Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Validation attributes in Silverlight, you must do one of three things:

1. Use a toolkit DataGrid to display the data - this automatically validates your properties (I have seen other controls do this, such as Telerik's RadGridView)
2. Validate manually in the property setter and throw a ValidationException if the value is not valid. You must also set ValidatesOnExceptions and NotifyOnValidationError to true in your Bindings.
3. [Implement INotifyDataErrorInfo or IDataError](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/validation/implementing-data-validation-in-silverlight-with-inotifydataerrorinfo) in your model and set validation errors through the methods in those interfaces.

Option 3 is the recommended approach and looks to be most suitable for your purposes.

Check out this link for more info msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(v=vs.95).aspx

Finally, the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface can be a little daunting - there is lots of plumbing to sort out before you can use it. However, [this post](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/11/15/jounce-part-7-validation-and-save-confirm-cancel-operations.aspx) from Jeremy Likness might help a little. 
Note that you do not have to validate in the setter as in the example.